# Parcelize compile error in Kotlin 1.7 when a property's type is a value class

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

In a project, I have a `Parcelize`-annotated data class that contains a property whose type is a value class. E.g.:

```
@Parcelize
data class Example(val id: Id) : Parcelable

@JvmInline
value class Id(val long: Long)
```

With Kotlin 1.6.10, this compiles and works. However, after updating to Kotlin 1.7.20, I started getting the following error a compile time:

> Type is not directly supported by 'Parcelize'. Annotate the parameter type with '@RawValue' if you want it to be serialized using 'writeValue()'

I'm not sure I understand why this stopped compiling, but is using `@RawValue` the actual solution, or is there a better one? It feels like a workaround that could break at runtime if the wrapped type changes to one that isn't `Parcelable`.